# How to install minicom under Windows 7?

Tags: terminal

Minicom is the terminal program, that I am used to. How do I get it for Windows, without building it from source, satisfying complex dependencies etc?

Comment: You don't `Minicom` is a Unix application so you have to compile it using `cygwin` and resolve the dependency problems that might surface which might include compiling them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install "cygwin", then minicom is available as a selectable package during installation.

Comment: I don't see minicom listed at http://cygwin.com/packages/ or https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html - looks like minicom is not a Cygwin provided or supported package?

Comment: Evidently they've removed it :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to boot from a CD or USB, you can try SystemRescueCd from https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/ - it ships with minicom and lrzsz which should meet most serial terminal needs. This is definitely not a "Windows minicom", but other than [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) or [TeraTerm](https://en.osdn.jp/projects/ttssh2/releases/) - it may be the next best thing?